# WebView Shows Blank Page

Tags: android, user-interface, webview

My Webview is loading an url. It takes more time for the url to get loaded. And in return I get a blank page/ white page. This works perfectly in emulator but not in any device ..Pls help me

```
mWebView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.paymentWebView);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);


            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {

             Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);

        }
    });


    mWebView.loadUrl("my url to be loaded");
```

Comment: Post your code along with the url.

Comment: This works perfectly in emulator but not in any device

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

by

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
        return false;
    }
```